# Fetching specific Goals for User code through complicated logic

Tags: django, django-models

I want to fetch a specific Goal through complicated logic for a certain User. Is this code supposed to go in the View or the Model?

If it is supposed to go in the Model, how would it be implemented, since User Model is written by Django and I can't add methods?

I realize this is not a specific error question but it seems to be that should be a no-brainer to you, gurus and consequently should not yield vague answer.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in the model or the view, or even do processing externally using a job/task queue like [celery](http://celeryproject.org/docs/django-celery/). In regards to the model vs. view question, I tend to prefer to put the logic into a view, especially if I need to process data from multiple models collectively. If you implement your logic as a method on your model, you can call it from a view or anywhere you might want. You could also implement caching very easily and store results on the model. Consider using AJAX to pull in the results asynchronously. You should also check the docs for info on [storing additional info about a user](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

**Store logic in view**

- Saves from needlessly complicating
  model
- Might be a better approach if you need to interact with multiple models
- Easy to implement and maintain
- Not as flexible, can't be reused everywhere

**Store logic on model**

- Makes it really easy to use all over your project, in views and/or scripts
- Easy to do caching on the model
- Potentially easy to customize the logic for a wide variety of usages through inheritance

Comment: So to recap, the best way would be to use UserProfile Model, that extends User with oneToOne field, and then in that model I should define my custom function for fetching goals oriented to that user?

Comment: Sure you can do that or use implement the processing in a view. I outlined some general pro/cons for each in my answer.